# SQL select from a table if 2 records exist

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a simple table `Foo` with columns `Customer_ID` and `App_ID`

I'm trying to select all customers from `CUSTOMER` table who have both `App 1` and `App 2` in `Foo` table.

I can do

```
SELECT C FROM CUSTOMER C 
INNER JOIN FOO F ON 
F.CUSTOMER_ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN APP A ON 
A.ID = F.APP_ID
WHERE A.NAME = 'App 1`
```

But that only gives me results when a customer has 1 app, i want results only if both apps are in `Foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would phrase this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT C.*
FROM CUSTOMER C 
INNER JOIN FOO F
    ON F.CUSTOMER_ID = C.ID
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM APP A WHERE A.ID = F.APP_ID AND A.NAME = 'App 1') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM APP A WHERE A.ID = F.APP_ID AND A.NAME = 'App 2');
```

If you wanted to this via joining, then you would need *two* joins to the `APP` table, e.g.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT C.*
FROM CUSTOMER C 
INNER JOIN FOO F
    ON F.CUSTOMER_ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN APP A1
    ON A1.ID = F.APP_ID
INNER JOIN APP A2
    ON A2.ID = F.APP_ID
WHERE
    A1.NAME = 'App 1' AND
    A2.NAME = 'App 2';
```

Note that I am using a distinct select above, because joining to `APP` twice may generate duplicate records.  Removing possible duplicates represents an extra step in the join approach which won't happen when using exists.

Comment: it looks good... but I cant for the life of me figure out why my results are empty when clearly there are records with both App 1 and 2

Comment: Without knowing your data, there isn't much more I can say here.

Comment: strange. if I select just one column instead of .* then it shows up. This is a good answer, thanks for the help